# How is the name formed when you commit to git if you specify other data and how safe is it?

Tags: git, github, pull

How is the name formed when you commit to git if you specify other data and how safe is it?

If I specify such data in the config in vs code, then we pass the commit with the name test

`git config --global user.name "test"  git config --global user.email "test@rambler.ru"`

`git config --global user.name "test2"  git config --global user.email "test2@rambler.ru"`

if I specify the name and email of another user in git and use the pool, will he get access to my codes? I don't understand how the git security system works?

I was looking for an answer to this question in the git documentation and did not find it in the search

[image] такими данными то комит проходит с именем test2

Comment: `user.name`/`user.email` are not credentials. They're commit identification data. They're used during commit creation and never used for authentication.

Comment: I understand that you can specify any data in them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fake+email

Comment: for now I’m just studying, so I realized that I can write any name and email and it doesn't affect anything

Comment: Anything can goes in locally. Major GIt hostings can be configured to check that pushed commits have known emails but you can still impersonate as any (known) account.

Comment: thank you, I realized that this is local data that does not affect access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git itself has no access restrictions. As you noticed, the committer is just a text field that anyone can write anything into.

If you need any access restrictions, this is up to the server hosting the git repository.

Comment: I don’t quite understand if I have a private repository and when I send a commit, I mean the name and email of another user, will another user get access to my codes?

Comment: The name and email associated with a commit is not related at all to who can access it.